# EF Code First - Run post-migration processing and cleanup

Tags: entity-framework, entity-framework-migrations

I am using Entity Framework 5.0 and have implemented custom migrations.

One thing that I'd like to do is perform some calculation and clean-up jobs after a specific migration is completed. I know that the `Seed()` method is used for post-migration data manipulation, but it is run with every migration. I want this to only run once after a specific migration is complete.

I would do it inside of the custom migration itself, but the processes require that I pull result sets and perform calculations on them, etc. and I'd like to do this in C# if possible (to utilize our job processing system).

What is the best way to run post-migration processing code for a specific migration?

Comment: What's wrong with placing that logic within the `Up()` method of your migration? You could also create a SPROC and execute it after migration.

Comment: As far as I know, in `Up()`, you can't use the context, etc., because the database isn't updated to the latest migration at that point. This would force me to do the work in `Sql()`'s, which I'm trying to avoid.

Comment: Given you're targeting a specific migration, you should have tables/columns known--so SQL shouldn't be that big a deal, no? You may be able to take advantage of `Appplication_Start`, but there's nothing to say it's a _specific_ migration, just that the database has been updated.

Answer (score 1):

I guess you could target a specific migration by interrogating the __MigrationHistory table. But that strikes me as being a bit fragile because you might want to re-scaffold migrations at some point. I think I would prefer to trigger the cleanup based on some other criteria.

Is there any way to detect that the data is "dirty"? Then the cleanup could be triggered when necessary.If that's not possible you could create a table in the database to hold flags that indicate when a cleanup is necessary. You could set the flag in the Up() method and remove it in the Down() method in a migration. Then you can check for the flag in the Seed() method and trigger the cleanup.

I think these are good [Tips for Entity Framework Migrations](http://elegantcode.com/2012/04/12/entity-framework-migrations-tips/)